# Graphics Card Upgrade

Tags: graphics-cards

I built a PC not very long ago. [Here](https://pcpartpicker.com/list/9YP6q4) are the specs (I have a different case, but I couldn't find the one I own, so I chose a similar one). My 1050Ti is a really good graphics card. It seems to be a great overclocker as well. However, as a huge surprise to no one, it can't get 60FPS in 1080p in ultra settings in AAA titles like GTA 5 as it's a budjet card. I'm looking for a graphics card which will be able to achieve that and maintain it for as long as possible. The 1070Ti looks like an attractive option, however I think it would be better for me to wait for the next generation NVidia cards. An 1160 and an 1170 have been rumored, however the 1160 especially needs to be taken with a grain of salt along with the rumored spcs. Lastly, it is said that NVidia currently are stuck with a large number of graphics cards because of the plummeting demand from miners. Should/Can I take advantage of this? I don't know anything about AMD cards, but that doesn't mean I won't accept an AMD card suggestion. My budjet is around 600-700$
Thanks!

Comment: If they are so overstocked the prices don't reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wait. FINALLY, it is more than a rumor that a new gaming architecture is coming. nVidia has a talk titled 'NVIDIA’s Next Generation Mainstream GPU' at the HotChips conference next month. Also, they are sending out invites to GamesCon on August 21 for a 'PC related event'. Yes that is a gaming conference. Read about it at [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2018/7/2/17524744/nvidia-geforce-gtx-1180-release-date-launch-rumors) here.

Other than that, if you really cannot wait or think you want to spend the money on the next generation, I would keep a hawk eye out for a 1080 Ti. I have already seen a couple of deals around $750 that disappear quickly. If new hardware really does come out and you keep looking, jump on one that is below your $700 threshold. It will happen

1080 Ti would be future proof for you. It will do 60 FPS with all setting on high and 1080P and you can even get 45-60 FPS with most setting high at 4K if you ever go there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was talking about the 1160 (ik it isn't really clear). I read the article you linked. I'll probably wait for the new cards to be released and then decide depending on what happens to the prices of current generation cards and the prices of the new ones. I won't get a 4K monitor for at least a few years, so you covered it.